Cant build project with wxWidgets and cmake
I'm on windows trying to build a project from github with cmake that requires wxwidgets.
I followed the directions located here https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2.5/overview_cmake.html for building with cmake.

Using the CMake GUI
Start the CMake GUI
Specify the wxWidgets root as your source folder
Specify a path where the build files should be created. It's recommended to use a path outside the wxWidgets root folder.
Press the Configure button and you will be asked which IDE or build system you wish to use
Optionally: Customize any of the options
Press the Generate button
Open the wxWidgets project with your preferred IDE

When I used the findpackages method cmake could not find wxwidgets so I tried this suggested code
set(wxWidgets_DIR "path/to/wxWidgets/lib/cmake/wxWidgets")

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED core base CONFIG) #Don't forget to add this 'CONFIG'
include(UsewxWidgets)

The above code results in this error
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/wxWidgets/lib/cmake/wxWidgets/wxWidgetsTargets.cmake:221 (message):
  The imported target "wx::wxbase" references the file

 "C:/Program Files (x86)/lib/vc_x64_dll/wxbase32ud.lib"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

After modifying the cmake list in the project to be like the one included in the minimal sample I get a new error.
The installation package was faulty and contained

 "C:/Program Files (x86)/wxWidgets/lib/cmake/wxWidgets/wxWidgetsTargets.cmake" 
  but not all the files it references.


"I followed the directions located here" - There are several "directions" in the referenced document. Please, add to the question your exact steps of building and installing wxWidgets.

@RYANRYTEL, what version of CMake and wxWidgets do you use? Can you build minimal sample with CMake?

@Igor cmake version 3.30.3 wxWidgets 3.2.6. The minimal sample did build.

@RYANRYTEL, look at what C.ake config file does and do the same in your project.

@igor where do i find that file

@RYANRYTEL, wxWidgets/samples/minimal, ofc.

You said that minimal sample built fine. How did you manage to build it without knowing where CMake configuration file is?

@igor I was confused because I was looking for a "cake" config

@RYANRYTEL, what is "cake" config? Never heard about this... :-)

@Igor " look at what C.ake config"

@RYANRYTEL. that was a typo. Should have been CMake... Sorry for the confusion.
